# jQueryUI autocomplete choices - styling issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to style an autocomplete list generated using jQueryUI. I can successfully style the text which appears in the input field once a choice is made, but am unable to style the list of possible values in the same manner. JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Cttt/3/).

Type 'ap' or 'boo' into the input field. You'll see that 'ap' is styled in a certain font and orange, which is what I want - see screenshot below. However, the list of possible values that appear is styled by the standard jQuery CSS and I cannot seem to turn that off. Using Chrome's developer tools I think the CSS class I need to change is **ui-autocomplete-input** but changing that makes no difference?

[image: screenshot]

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var availableIndustries = [
        "apparel",
        "books"];
    $("#industry-list").autocomplete({
        source: availableIndustries
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[type=image]")
        .button()
        .click(function (event) {

        var constants = {
            'apparel': 'apparel.pdf',
                'books': 'publishing.pdf'
        };
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
    .ui-state-default { background:none; border:none; }
    .ui-state-hover { background:none; border:none; }
    .ui-widget input { font-family:'Istok Web', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #DD4814;}
    .go_button { position: relative; top: 12px; }
```

Comment: Override/edit the css for these classes ".ui-state-focus" and ".ui-menu-item a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Override/edit the css for these classes ".ui-state-focus" and ".ui-menu-item a"
Below is override the css,

```
.ui-menu-item a{ font-family:'Istok Web', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #DD4814;}

    .ui-state-focus{
        background:none!important;
        border:none!important;
        font-family:'Istok Web', sans-serif!important;
        font-size: 16px!important;
        color: #DD4814!important;
    }
```

Edit on existing CSS, Find the class name ".ui-state-focus" remove the background property and add the additional style property as seperate for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to apply your required css to following class
.ui-menu-item { font-family:'Istok Web', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #DD4814;}